# Grails Unit testing - mock findAllBy() method with each closure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mockito, spock

I want to Unit test a function in a service class.

The service class looks like this:

```
    class FooService{ 

    Double getFoo(SomeClass class){
      Double returningValue = 0.0
      String parameter

      SomeClass.findAllByCodeLike(parameter).each{
        Double amount = someOtherFooServiceMethod(it,it.someClassAttribute?.intValue())
        if(amount){
         returningValue += amount;
         }
       }
     }

    }
```

I know how to mock the *SomeClass.findAllByCodeLike(parameter)*. I mocked it with the *SomeClass.metaClass.static.findAllByCodeLike()* and assign to this function a value.

But i don't know how to mock the *.each{}*. 
Is there way to do it?

By now I'm mocking a lot of domain classes to test this method and also save the domain classes into the in memory database. If i find a way to mock *SomeClass.findAllByCodeLike(parameter).each{...}* i can reduce the TestClass by a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to mock the `each{}`. You shoud simply make your `findAllByCodeLike` mock return a list of values:

```
SomeClass.metaClass.static.findAllByCodeLike = { code -> [ new SomeClass(...), new SomeClass(...), ... ] }
//...
SomeClass.findAllByCodeLike(parameter).each{ 
  doStuff it
}
```

Comment: Caveat: If there is another test method following the one which mocked the static method via meta-class and that latter test method expects the original static method to be present, you will get into trouble because what you did in one test will bleed into the next one. So always clean up your test fixtures. In Spock you would do `setup: def originalMetaClass = SomeClass.metaClass` and at the end `cleanup: SomeClass.metaClass = originalMetaClass`, in JUnit the analogous thing in another way.